# Hadoop, successful Map Reduce jobs but no output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

**Objective:**

I am trying to merge data using Map Reduce. I have multiple group of data within the same folder.

**Method:**

So I run Map Reduce merging jobs for multiple times sequentially within a program / flow.

**Problem:**

The problem that I am facing is not failed jobs but successful jobs with no output. The first one (sometimes two ) iteration(s) always have output (part-r-00000) but not the following. I am using sample datasets that is very small in size and volume (1 ~ 2 kb, around 5 files)

**What I tried:**

Making the thread to sleep for 5 seconds after every run but to no avail. I tried to check using webhdfs after a longer while, theres still no such file.

Could you please enlighten me on this? Thanks in advance.

**Picture:**

[image: Problem]

**Code:**

```
/*
* To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
* To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package mergedata;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileStatus;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;

import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

/**
 *
 * @author abcdefg
 */
public class MergeData extends Configured implements Tool{

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static class ReadMapper
extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{
    @Override
    public void map(Object key, Text value, Mapper.Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        context.write(new Text(value.toString()),  new IntWritable(1));
    }
}

public static class MergeReducer
extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
            Reducer.Context context
    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        result.set(sum);
        context.write(key, result);
    }
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Configuration conf = getConf();

    FileSystem hdfs = FileSystem.get(conf);

    args = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (args.length != 3) {
        System.err.println(args.length);
        System.err.println("Usage: mergedata <input folder> <temporary folder> <output folder>");
        System.exit(1);
    }
//        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
//        ContentSummary cs = fs.getContentSummary(new Path(args[0]));
//        long fileCount = cs.getFileCount();

    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);

    job.setJarByClass(MergeData.class);
    job.setMapperClass(ReadMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(MergeReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
//        String files = ().replaceAll(",", "," + args[0] + "/");
//        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, files);

    int jobComplete = 1;
    FileStatus[] fileStatus = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(args[0]));

    HashMap<String,Pair<String,Long>> map = new HashMap<String,Pair<String,Long>>();

    String tempName;
    String tempKey;
    Path tempPath;
    for (FileStatus fileStatu : fileStatus) {

        tempPath = fileStatu.getPath();
        tempName = tempPath.getName();
        tempKey = tempName.substring(0,12);
        if (map.containsKey(tempKey)) {
            map.put(tempKey,new Pair(map.get(tempKey).getLeft() + "," +
                    tempPath.toString(),
                    map.get(tempKey).getRight() + fileStatu.getLen()));
        } else {
            map.put(tempKey, new Pair(tempPath.toString(),fileStatu.getLen()));
        }
    }

    String[] files = map.keySet().toArray(new String[map.keySet().size()]);
    String[] inputFiles;
//        String[] files = args[1].split(",");
    for (String file : files)
    {
        System.out.println("file = " + file);
//            FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0] + "/" + file + "*"));
        System.out.println(args[2] + "/" + file);
        if (hdfs.exists(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file))) {
            System.out.println(file + " exists in " + args[2]);
            map.put(file,new Pair(
                    map.get(file).getLeft() + "," + args[2] + "/" + file,
                    map.get(file).getRight() + hdfs.getFileStatus(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file)).getLen()
            ));
        }
        System.out.println("MR job input files : " + map.get(file).getLeft());
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, map.get(file).getLeft());

        System.out.println("MR job output dir : " + args[1] + "/" + file);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job ,new Path(args[1] + "/" + file));
        if (hdfs.exists(new Path(args[1] + "/" + file))) {
            hdfs.delete(new Path(args[1] + "/" + file), true); // Shouldn't occur
        }
        jobComplete = Math.max(jobComplete, (job.waitForCompletion(true))? 0 : 1);
            // hdfs.getFileStatus(tempFile)
        if (job.isSuccessful()) {
                // Following sequence includes size check before deleting files

            FileStatus[] filesStatuz = hdfs.listStatus(new Path(args[1] + "/" + file + "/part-r-00000"));

            System.out.println("filesStatuz[0].getLen() = " + filesStatuz[0].getLen());
            System.out.println("totalLen = " + map.get(file).getRight());
            if (filesStatuz[0].getLen() >= map.get(file).getRight()) {

                if (hdfs.exists(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file))) {
                    System.out.println("Found the main file of " + file);
                    hdfs.rename(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file), new Path(args[2] + "/" + file + "_tmp"));
                }
                hdfs.rename(new Path(args[1] + "/" + file + "/part-r-00000"), new Path(args[2] + "/" + file));
                hdfs.delete(new Path(args[1] + "/" + file), true);
                System.out.println("Done safe replacement");

//                    hdfs.delete(new Path(args[0] + "/" + file + "*"), false);
                inputFiles = map.get(file).getLeft().split(",");
                for (String inputFile : inputFiles) {
                    if (!inputFile.equals(args[2] + "/" + file)) {
                        hdfs.delete(new Path(inputFile), false);
                        System.out.println(inputFile + " has been deleted");
                    }
                }
                if (hdfs.exists(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file + "_tmp"))) {
                    hdfs.delete(new Path(args[2] + "/" + file + "_tmp"), false);
                    System.out.println("Deleted previous main file of " + file);
                }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Merging of " + file +"might have failed. Input and output size doesn't tally");
            }
        }         
    }
    return(jobComplete);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new MergeData(), args);
    System.exit(exitCode);
}

public class Pair<L,R> {

    private final L left;
    private final R right;

    public Pair(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }
    public L getLeft() { return left; }
    public R getRight() { return right; }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { return left.hashCode() ^ right.hashCode(); }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Pair)) return false;
        Pair pairo = (Pair) o;
        return this.left.equals(pairo.getLeft()) &&
                this.right.equals(pairo.getRight());
    }

}
}
```

**Flow:**

The essence is that it will combine files of similar date eg: cdr_20150701_0, cdr_20150701_1 in input folder (args[0]) to a main file eg: cdr_20150701 and to be placed in merged folder (args[3]). But if such a main file exist before the merging, then all the files eg.: cdr_20150701_0, cdr_20150701_1 and cdr_20150701 will be merged to a new cdr_20150701. The part-0-00000 will be stored in a temporary folder (args[1]). After successful transfer, the temporary folder and the parts will be deleted.

Comment: it seems that the input directory/file does not exist...

Comment: Can you post the code of the job you are trying to run? That is not a successful job, it has a FileNotFoundException which is clearly the problem.

Comment: just the Driver class should be enough for start... I guess that it is simply the problem of not setting the input Path of the second job as the output path of the first...

Comment: I have added code and explanation of flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you try to use  the command getmerge, maybe it can be usefull in your case. If you only do a merge with your data maybe you don't need a map reduce job only for a merge.

hadoop fs -getmerge   [addnl]

Takes a source directory and a destination file as input and concatenates files in src into the destination local file. Optionally addnl can be set to enable adding a newline character at the end of each file.

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: I have taken your advice and it is now working like a charm, in Java it is called copyMerge. Thanks